# How to add a new Key value pair in Node.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the JSON that I have:

```
[
    "Spain",
    "2010",
    "Brazil",
    "1994",
    "Brazil",
    "1970",
    "Brazil",
    "1962",
    "Brazil",
    "2002",
    "Brazil",
    "1958",
    "Germany",
    "2014",
    "Germany",
    "1990",
    "Germany",
    "1974",
    "Germany",
    "1954",
    "Italy",
    "2006",
    "Italy",
    "1982",
    "Italy",
    "1938",
    "Italy",
    "1934",
    "France",
    "2018",
    "France",
    "1998",
    "Argentina",
    "1986",
    "Argentina",
    "1978",
    "Uruguay",
    "1930",
    "Uruguay",
    "1950",
    "England",
    "1966"
]
```

I'm trying to convert it into multiple array objects of key-value pair like below.

```
{
        "name": "Spain",
        "year": 2010
    },
    {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "year": 1994, 1970, 1962, 2002, 1958
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there any way to achieve the above structure? I have tried couple of methods using array map function but it doesn't give in the desired output.

```
const dataMap = Object.keys(s).map((filename) => {
      return {
        name: filename,
        year: s[filename]
    }
    })
```

How can it be done in Node.js??

Comment: Shouldn't `year` property be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const arr=["Spain","2010","Brazil","1994","Brazil","1970","Brazil","1962","Brazil","2002","Brazil","1958","Germany","2014","Germany","1990","Germany","1974","Germany","1954","Italy","2006","Italy","1982","Italy","1938","Italy","1934","France","2018","France","1998","Argentina","1986","Argentina","1978","Uruguay","1930","Uruguay","1950","England","1966"];

const map = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  const country = arr[i],
    year = arr[i + 1];

  if (map.has(country)) map.get(country).push(year);
  else map.set(country, [year]);
}

const result = [];
for (let [name, year] of map.entries()) {
  result.push({ name, year });
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by looping over your array 2 indexes at a time. For each iteration, you can obtain the place + the year, and create a key-value pair using the place as the key and an array of years as the value. If you come across a place that you've already seen, you can add it to the array at your key in the Map. Lastly, you can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function to build your array of objects from the Map:

```js
const arr = ["Spain","2010","Brazil","1994","Brazil","1970","Brazil","1962","Brazil","2002","Brazil","1958","Germany","2014","Germany","1990","Germany","1974","Germany","1954","Italy","2006","Italy","1982","Italy","1938","Italy","1934","France","2018","France","1998","Argentina","1986","Argentina","1978","Uruguay","1930","Uruguay","1950","England","1966"];

const map = new Map;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  const name = arr[i];
  const year = arr[i+1];
  map.set(name, (map.get(name) || []).concat(year));
}
const res = Array.from(map, ([name, year]) => ({name, year}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with a few steps. Create a temporary map (using a plain object or a `Map` class). Fill that map using even and odd indexes (even indexes become key and the odd indexes become part of the array) and then convert the map into an array.

```js
const sourceArray = [
    "Spain",
    "2010",
    "Brazil",
    "1994",
    "Brazil",
    "1970",
    "Brazil",
    "1962",
    "Brazil",
    "2002",
    "Brazil",
    "1958",
    "Germany",
    "2014",
    "Germany",
    "1990",
    "Germany",
    "1974",
    "Germany",
    "1954",
    "Italy",
    "2006",
    "Italy",
    "1982",
    "Italy",
    "1938",
    "Italy",
    "1934",
    "France",
    "2018",
    "France",
    "1998",
    "Argentina",
    "1986",
    "Argentina",
    "1978",
    "Uruguay",
    "1930",
    "Uruguay",
    "1950",
    "England",
    "1966"
];

const map = {};

for(let i =0; i < sourceArray.length;i+=2){
  const country = sourceArray[i];
  if(map[country]){
      map[country].push(+sourceArray[i+1])
  }else{
     map[country] = [+sourceArray[i+1]]
  }
}

const finalArray = Object.entries(map).map(([k,v])=> ({ name:k, years :v}))
console.log(finalArray)
```